# How to redirect user's browser to external link

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.js and javascript.
I want to redirect the user's browser using a function after doing some calculations in node.js.

here's my code

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/number/:num', (req, res) =>{
  var user_num = req.params.num;
  user_num = user_num + 10; // here, I do some calculations like this
  go(user_num)
});

function go(nu){
  var number_2 = nu + "1"; // some calculations here too.
  //here I want to redirect user to a url with the number_2 on the url.
  
 // www.mydomain.com/number/?id=number_2 <==== LIKE THIS
}
app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening to port 3000...'));
```

Is there any method to redirect the user like that? Please help. Thanks

Comment: Did you look up redirect in express docs?

Comment: @charlietfl I' will bro. Thanks for the comment <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
res.redirect(`/number/?id=${number_2}`);
```

This should do the trick if you want to redirect to a local url.

```
res.status(301).redirect(`www.mydomain.com/number/?id=${number_2}`);
```

This will redirect to an external url.
I suggest reading into [Express docs](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html) and [HTTP statuses](https://httpstatuses.com/).

Comment: I'm getting this error. "res is not defined." Should I use it like this?
app.get('/', (req , res) =>{
   res.redirect(`/number/?id=${number_2}`);
});

Comment: You can move the calculations into the first GET method and do the redirect there.
Also, I suggest reading into HTTP methods and when you should use which one.